# Steeping/Mashing Cara- Grains

Tags: mash, steeping, specialty-grains

I have a smaller (5 gallon) mash tun. I recently mashed 14 lbs and was only able to get a mash to water ratio of 1.2 and filled the tun!.  Temp was right on, but I only got 55% efficiency.

I have a recipe with 9 lbs of base malt and 6 lbs specialty (Cara-helles and Caravienne).  Can I mash the base malts and only steep the specialty malts to reduce the amount of grain in my mash tun and still get good extraction from the specialty?  I want to avoid mashing twice to shorten my brew day.

Comment: "I have a recipe with 9 lbs of base malt and 6 lbs specialty (Cara-helles and Caravienne)."  That's a ridiculous amount of crystal malt! Can you post the full recipe?

Comment: Its an IPA that I am trying to get around 7.5 ABV (similar to Great Lakes Commodore Perry IPA): 9lbs base malt, 3lbs cara-helles, 2lbs caravienne, 1/2 lb rye, 2 oz bittering hops @ 60 mins, 2 oz flavor hops @ 15 min, 1 oz dry hop using Wyeast 1007 (my personal favorite)

Comment: At almost 50% crystal malt, you might have misinterpreted your recipe, or gotten a bad recipe.  But this doesn't necessarily explain your poor efficiency.

Comment: @brewchez : you are completely correct.  I was trying to increase the amount of specialty malt in order to reduce the mash volume.  The original recipe was for Vienna malt.  I switched to the specialty.Using Brewsmith to increase amounts to get %ABV

Comment: Bad idea....totally different result.

Comment: How about this....  I can use the original Vienna malt and utilize an BIAB technique on it (I used this before all-grain).  Can I then use this wort for my fly sparge water?

Comment: A 5 gallon tun is difficult to do 5 gallon batches in, unless they are fairly low gravity and low water to grain ratio. If I had a 5 gallon tun and wanted to mash a high gravity beer, I would probably split it in half and mash/sparge it twice. That or just assume lower efficiency and adjust your grains accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You typically do not need to mash Cara-helles or Caravienne.  They are fully converted during the process used to make them the crystal malts that they are.  They can be steeped in your wort post lautering and pre-boil.

Comment: Or they can just be steeped in water and that added to the kettle along with the wort from your mash.

Comment: Yeah, they are typically mashed for convenience, but it is not required.